# is there a more elegant syntax for Swift Filter with 2 parameters

Tags: swift

Is there a more elegant way to filter with an additional parameter (or map, reduce).

When I filter with a single parameter, we get a beautiful easy to ready syntax

```
let numbers = Array(1...10)

func isGreaterThan5(number:Int) -> Bool {
    return number > 5
}

numbers.filter(isGreaterThan5)
```

However, if I need to pass an additional parameter to my function it turns out ugly

```
func isGreaterThanX(number:Int,x:Int) -> Bool {
    return number > x
}

numbers.filter { (number) -> Bool in
    isGreaterThanX(number: number, x: 8)
}
```

I would like to use something like

```
numbers.filter(isGreaterThanX(number: $0, x: 3))
```

but this gives a compile error annonymous closure argument not contained in a closure

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could change your function to return a closure which serves
as predicate for the filter method:

```
func isGreaterThan(_ lowerBound: Int) -> (Int) -> Bool {
    return { $0 > lowerBound }
}

let filtered = numbers.filter(isGreaterThan(5))
```

`isGreaterThan` is a function taking an `Int` argument and returning
a closure of type `(Int) -> Bool`. The returned closure "captures"
the value of the given lower bound.

If you make the function generic then it can be used with
other comparable types as well:

```
func isGreaterThan<T: Comparable>(_ lowerBound: T) -> (T) -> Bool {
    return { $0 > lowerBound }
}

print(["D", "C", "B", "A"].filter(isGreaterThan("B")))
```

In this particular case however, a literal closure is also easy to read:

```
let filtered = numbers.filter( { $0 > 5 })
```

---

And just for the sake of completeness: Using the fact that
[Instance Methods are Curried Functions in Swift](https://oleb.net/blog/2014/07/swift-instance-methods-curried-functions/), this would work as well:

```
extension Comparable {
    func greaterThanFilter(value: Self) -> Bool {
        return value > self
    }
}

let filtered = numbers.filter(5.greaterThanFilter)
```

but the "reversed logic" might be confusing.

---

*Remark:* In earlier Swift versions you could use a curried function
syntax:

```
func isGreaterThan(lowerBound: Int)(value: Int) -> Bool {
    return  value > lowerBound
}
```

but this feature has been [removed in Swift 3.](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0002-remove-currying.md)

Comment: good job! I dont know this definition, but for me better is version with 
brackets `func isGreaterThan(_ lowerBound: Int) -> ((Int) -> Bool)`

Comment: @AdrianBobrowski: You can write the additional parentheses if you like, to make it more clear. The result is the same.